# How to use Task.Delay to control time spans between calls to a web service

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, winrt-async

When a user takes a certain action a call (get) to a web service is made. The service doesn't allow for calls more frequent than once per second. I was thinking I could use Task.Delay to control this so that subsequent calls are made at least one second apart in time but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
public async void OnUserAction()
{
    var timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 1000ms - (Now - previousWaitStartTime);
    var timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = Max(0, timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade + 1000ms);
    previousWaitStartTime = Now;
    await Task.Delay(timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade);
    MakeCallToWebService();
}
```

Calls and contiunations are done on same thread (as reported by Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId).
The problem is that if there's a quick succession of invocations of this method the passed time between calls to the web service is less than 1s. I've either done a silly mistake or I don't fully understand Task.Delay (or both of the above). Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that your problem happens when a request is queued up when another one is already waiting. Here's my take on your pseudo code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThrottledAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Queue up multiple user actions
            // within a short interval.
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                OnUserAction();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int UserActionID;
        private static DateTime previousWaitStartTime;

        public static async void OnUserAction()
        {
            // Keep track of the operation ID.
            var userActionID = Interlocked.Increment(ref UserActionID);

            // Pseudo-code implementation.
            var timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 1000 - (int)(DateTime.Now.Subtract(previousWaitStartTime).TotalMilliseconds);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0:HH:mm:ss.ffff} - User action {1}: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = {2}.",
                DateTime.Now, userActionID, timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade);

            var timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = Math.Max(0, timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade + 1000);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0:HH:mm:ss.ffff} - User action {1}: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = {2}.",
                DateTime.Now, userActionID, timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade);

            previousWaitStartTime = DateTime.Now;

            await Task.Delay(timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade);
            await MakeCallToWebService(userActionID);
        }

        private static async Task MakeCallToWebService(int userActionID)
        {
            // Simulate network delay.
            await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(5, 10));

            Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm:ss.ffff} - User action {1}: web service call.", DateTime.Now, userActionID);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
19:10:11.1366 - User action 1: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = -2147482648.
19:10:11.1416 - User action 1: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 0.
19:10:11.1536 - User action 2: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 988.
19:10:11.1536 - User action 2: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1988.
19:10:11.1586 - User action 1: web service call.
19:10:11.1646 - User action 3: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.1646 - User action 3: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.1756 - User action 4: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.1756 - User action 4: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.1866 - User action 5: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.1866 - User action 5: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.1976 - User action 6: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.1986 - User action 6: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.2086 - User action 7: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.2086 - User action 7: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.2186 - User action 8: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.2196 - User action 8: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.2296 - User action 9: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.2296 - User action 9: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:11.2406 - User action 10: timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade = 990.
19:10:11.2406 - User action 10: timeToWaitBeforeThisCallShouldBeMade = 1990.
19:10:13.1567 - User action 2: web service call.
19:10:13.1717 - User action 3: web service call.
19:10:13.1877 - User action 5: web service call.
19:10:13.1877 - User action 4: web service call.
19:10:13.2107 - User action 6: web service call.
19:10:13.2187 - User action 7: web service call.
19:10:13.2187 - User action 8: web service call.
19:10:13.2357 - User action 9: web service call.
19:10:13.2537 - User action 10: web service call.
```

You should really be using the right tool for the job. How about a `SemaphoreSlim`?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThrottledAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Queue up simultaneous calls.
            MakeThrottledCall();
            MakeThrottledCall();
            MakeThrottledCall();
            MakeThrottledCall();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Used to throttle our web service calls.
        // Max degree of parallelism: 1.
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim WebServiceMutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

        private static async void MakeThrottledCall()
        {
            // Wait for the previous call
            // (and delay task) to complete.
            await WebServiceMutex.WaitAsync();

            try
            {
                await MakeCallToWebService();

                // Report the completion of your web service call if necessary.

                // Delay for a bit before releasing the semaphore.
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Allow the next web service call to go through.
                WebServiceMutex.Release();
            }
        }

        private static async Task MakeCallToWebService()
        {
            // Simulate network delay.
            await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(5, 10));

            Console.WriteLine("WebServiceCall: {0:HH:mm:ss.ffff}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: `MakeThrottledCall` no longer returns `Task` as per svick's comment.

Comment: I don't like your solution, because `MakeThrottledCall()` should complete (more precisely, the `Task` it returns should complete) right after `MakeCallToWebService()` completes, not a second later.

Comment: @svick, you are making a fair point. I don't have a nice solution to that - only ugly hackery such as a fire-and-forget call to `Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ => Semaphore.Release());` The described solution is not a widely applicable pattern for async throttling in general. However, it does address the specific situation described by the question (and you would note that the original `OnUserAction` is a `void`), so I'm sticking by it for now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested alternative solution, will try it out. However, your assumption about the time between subsequent calls to the web service is not correct. Since it is expressed as `Max(0, timeUntilPreviousCallWillBeOrWasMade + 1000ms)` the wait time for the latest invoked call will be at least 1000ms when the previous calls has not yet been made (and less than 1000ms when it already has been made). So the question remains, why is the time between subsequent calls sometimes less than 1000ms?

Comment: @Christian, I missed the + 1000ms. However, all that changes is the time between the first and second concurrent calls - after that they start firing like a machine gun. You are only considering the previous call's wait start, which *does not* give you the complete picture. When more than two requests are made really close to one another, `previousWaitStartTime` is set to roughly the same value multiple times and you base your calculations on it ending up with multiple delay tasks elapsing at roughly the same time.

Comment: Ah but of course, I feel a bit stupid now :) I thought I'd only needed to consider the previous call which of course isn't true since I'm calculating with time diffs. I modified your code with `++_callsPending; await Task.Delay(_callsPending * 1000); --_callsPending;` which gave more reasonable numbers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Christian, happens to the best of us. Glad I could help.

Answer (score -4):

Can you use Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout) at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)?

I suggest you to use that.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is not available in .NET for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: ... and even if it was, it would not solve the problem because Task.Delay and Thread.Sleep are offering the same feature (waiting for a certain ammount of time), except that Thread.Sleep would block a thread which is exactly whay we want to avoid when using Tasks and async/await constructs.